# Gensim Lemmatization Remove Postag b'

Tags: gensim, lemmatization

I am trying to lemmatize documents with the following codes. Lemmatization works. It produces byte string. Therefore, the next part of the codes produces "cant concan byte to str" error. Then I have changed tokens as str() as given in below codes. The output of the code is as given below;(I am using Python 3.7 (64 bit))

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-223-cb505389f802> in <module>
      1 #Build a Vocabulary
----> 2 model.build_vocab(train_demo_corpus)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\doc2vec.py in build_vocab(self, documents, update, progress_per, keep_raw_vocab, trim_rule, **kwargs)
    727         """
    728         total_words, corpus_count = self.vocabulary.scan_vocab(
--> 729             documents, self.docvecs, progress_per=progress_per, trim_rule=trim_rule)
    730         self.corpus_count = corpus_count
    731         report_values = self.vocabulary.prepare_vocab(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\doc2vec.py in scan_vocab(self, documents, docvecs, progress_per, trim_rule)
    807         for document_no, document in enumerate(documents):
    808             if not checked_string_types:
--> 809                 if isinstance(document.words, string_types):
    810                     logger.warning(
    811                         "Each 'words' should be a list of words (usually unicode strings). "

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'words'
```

here is my code;

```py
train_demo_corpus = list(lemmat(lee_train_demo_file))

def lemmat(fname, tokens_only=False):
    with smart_open.smart_open(fname, encoding="iso-8859-1") as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            tokens = gensim.utils.lemmatize(line)
            if tokens_only:
                yield str(tokens)
            else:
                # For training data, add tags
                yield str(gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(tokens, [i]))

model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=50, min_count=2, epochs=40)
model.build_vocab(train_demo_corpus)
```

Best regards,

Comment: 'b' denotes a byte string.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal for more info.  You can Google for a lot of info on how to work with this.

Comment: Yes, as @bivouac0 notes, the `b'` you're seeing isn't part of the string, but an indicator to you, the programmer, of its type. If you're printing a raw Python object (like the `TaggedDocument`), it's proper for it to appear. On the other hand, if you try printing such a string like the first word of the first document directly – `print (train_demo_corpus[0].words[0])` – it shoudn't appear. So if there's some other problem with it, please add more details as to why it's a problem.

Comment: hi @gojomo, let me specify the problem: in the next step I got "TypeError: can't concat str to bytes" when the following codes run:                                          
model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=50, min_count=2, epochs=40)  model.build_vocab(train_demo_corpus) ... My question is why the codes given in my question produce binary output? How can I decode them as str?

Comment: I'd need to see the whole error stack (with lines of code & line numbers) to understand that next error you've received. You could edit your question to add it, so you have more space & formatting options than in these comments. (Also, as such encoding/string-type issues vary a bit between Python 2.x & Python 3.x, please mention which you're using.)

Comment: I have just edited my question with your feedbacks...

Comment: It would have been better to add the new info, rather than changing completely what the question is about. But, the current problem with your code is that your `lemmat()` function is yielding strings. `Doc2Vec` requires each item in its training-corpus to be a `TaggedDocument`-shaped object, with `words` and `tags` properties. Chang your `yield` line to simply `yield TaggedDocument(tags, [i])` and you won't get the current error.

Comment: Hi @gojomo, actually, "else" part is for training corpus. Therefore, as you can see, it is very similar to your suggestion. As I have tried to explain in the body of question, the code produces byte string and the code "model.build_vocab(train_demo_corpus)" gives "TypeError: can't concat str to bytes." That's why I have used "str()". Btw, when I have used "tokens = gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(line)" instead of "tokens = gensim.utils.lemmatize(line..." everything is fine.

Comment: There's no `TypeError` described, with full error message and stack, in your current question text, so it's hard to help debug that. The error which is shown, `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'words'`, would be completely solved by not applying `str()` over the `TaggedDocument`. So it's unclear what problem you still have, if any.

Answer (score 1):

The `lemmatize` function in `gensim.utils` encodes the lamma into a byte string via `lemma.encode('utf8')`. You can either remove the `.encode('utf8')` in your local files for gensim, create your own copy of lemmatize and remove the encoding or add the following to your code:

```
tokens = gensim.utils.lemmatize(line)
b' '.join(tokens).decode('utf-8').split(' ')
```